# direct_to_template and render_to_response on templates - {{request}}

Tags: django, templates, django-generic-views

These functions should not work exactly the same?

```
def IndexView(request):
    return direct_to_template(request, template='index.html')

def IndexView2(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                              {'request': request},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm not asking the difference between both, but why on template I cannot use the {{request}} when I use the direct_to_template...
I read a lot of similar questions, but yet I cannot figure out.

Does anyone knows why? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `direct_to_template` actually uses `RequestContext(request)` by default (as do all the generic views), meaning that all your template context processors are available in the template (including [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) which is what makes the `request` variable accessible).

When you use the [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), it scans all the template context processors (as defined in  [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)) and automatically adds them to the context so that they are available in your template. From the docs:

> The second difference is that it automatically populates the context with a few variables, according to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add django.core.context_processors.request to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py.